# Magento 2: Creating a custom layout

Tags: magento2, module, layout, custom

I'm having trouble creating a custom layout. I have successfully created a layout called `home_page.xml` which is a copy of the default 1column layout.

I have selected this layout for my home page, but can't seem to add any content to it. Am I limited to only adding containers to the `home_page.xml` file? No HTML that I add will appear on my home page.

I've been reading on how to create and reference containers but it doesn't make a lot of sense, and I'm not sure what files I need to create in order to do so.

Here is my `home_page.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>

        <div id="test123"><p>This is a test</p></div>

        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

The div doesn't show up. I can successfully remove the header and footer containers however, so I know that the layout file is working successfully.

My ultimate goal is to add a full width content slider directly under the header on the home page. Any help is extremely appreciated. I've been searching around for a couple days and have run out of new content to study.

Answer (score 10):

The problem here is that you're **misunderstanding containers and blocks**.

In M2, there is a **new concept of containers which are containers for blocks but not real block**, they are used to *define the structure of a page in the XML* and then blocks are assigned to containers.

> A container exists for the sole purpose of assigning content structure
>   to a page. A container has no additional content except the content of
>   included elements. Examples of containers include the header, left column, main column, and footer.
>
> A block represents each feature on a page and employs templates to
>   generate the HTML to insert into its parent structural block. Examples
>   of blocks include a category list, a mini cart, product tags, and
>   product listing.

Definition of a container from the official doc:

> A structure without content that holds other layout elements such as
>   blocks and containers.
>
> Details: A container renders child elements during view output
>   generation. It can be empty or it can contain an arbitrary set of
>   `<container>` and `<block>` elements.

Only blocks are being rendered even if the framework generates the container based on the attributes you specified.

You can find more informations at the following links:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html
- http://alankent.me/2015/01/24/magento-2-containers-and-blocks/

To implement your new layout you need to create a container instead of your div:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>

        <container name="content" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column content"/>

        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Then in the layout XML related to your new page you can use the following code to add a block to your container:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="Package_Module::test.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Finally you can write the following code in your `test.phtml` template:

```
<div id="test123"><p>This is a test</p></div>
```

On the other hand, if you need the div to be a container you can simply do:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>

        <container name="test" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column content" htmlId="test123" />

        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

That will give you the following container which then you can use (as explained above) to add blocks into it.

```
<div id="test123" class="content column"></div>
```

Comment: I have my layout file located at: 

'app > design > frontend > CW > default > Magento_Theme > page_layout > home_page.xml'

Where should the layout XML related to my new page be located? Also, where should my .phtml template be located?

Thank you very much for your response. You have already been extremely helpful.

Comment: It depends on how you declare a controller for your new page ? What layout handle do you have available for your module ?

Comment: I guess I have more to learn than I thought. What do you mean by layout handle? All I've done is created the home_page.xml layout and selected it on the backend of Magento on my home page.   
  
My ultimate goal is to create a jquery slider as I have done on this website www.cyberwarecomputers.com right below the header. Magento 1 was much more developer friendly!   
  
Also, adding the code '<container name="test" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column content" htmlId="test123" />' to my home_page.xml layout file is not adding any HTML to my home page.

Comment: Can i reuse the contents of a container? that is can i duplicate the contents of a container inside a new container.