# magento 2 how to add phtml file after after_body_start

Tags: magento2, layout

In **magento1** we use this reference to add block after body tag.

```
<reference name="after_body_start">
</reference>
```

same also use in **magento 1**

```
 <reference name="before_body_end"></reference>
```

**what is replacement of this code in magento 2?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can check inside `page_layout/empty.xml` file inside `module-theme/base` folder.

```
<container name="after.body.start" as="after.body.start" before="-" label="Page Top"/>

<container name="before.body.end" as="before_body_end" after="-" label="Page Bottom"/>
```

You can check reference from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`  here also:

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="head.components" as="components" template="Magento_Catalog::js/components.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

So in Magento 2 , you can use `referenceContainer` node to define same as in Magento 1.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Refer working example, you can place it `default.xml` or specific layout file in your module.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Manufacturer\Grid" name="manufacturer_grid" template="templates\test.phtml"  before="before.body.end">
            </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

If you want to add before or after you can create reference container as posted.

```
before= "before.body.end"
after = "before.body.end"
```

Here is an excellent answer from [Raphael](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106535/magento-2-creating-a-custom-layout)

Hope this helps ....:)

Comment: @Qaisar Satti , I added this in my module ( Vendorname\Modulename\view\frontend\layout\default.xml  ), it is working fine. you can not find the string `name="before_body_end"` anymore in Magento 2. check the file `\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\adminhtml\page_layout\admin-1column.xml` it is `name="before.body.end"  as="before_body_end" `  the name is used as an alias. we have to use reference container name as i mentioned to add phtml.