# Magento 2 Add some content before body closing tag on every page

Tags: magento2, page

I'm using magento 2 , and I would need to add some content before the body closing tag , on every page. What's the most correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `before.body.end` as the reference name and add the block using layout/default xml

Here is an example: [Magento 2 add script before closing body tag](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102785/magento-2-add-script-before-closing-body-tag)

Look at KAndy's answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply add block with xml add this in `default.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="beforebody"  template="Magento_Theme::beforebody.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

[reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117195/magento-2-how-to-add-phtml-file-after-after-body-start)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is via the Magento Admin:

```
Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Design -> Footer -> Miscellaneous HTML
```

Another option via the Magento Admin is to use a widget to include a static block:

```
Admin -> Content -> Widget: CMS Static Block
  Layout Updates: 
     Display on: All Pages
     Container: Page Bottom
```

If creating/customizing a theme then you could consider using layout XML to include a template or static block.