# Creating a custom homepage template in Magento2.1.5

Tags: magento2.1.5

i know this question is already here.But i have tried all things. And nothing works for me.i need help, i am new to magento i have created a custom theme as default theme. Now i am trying to create a custom page template like **app\design\frontend\accu\accu-theme\magento_theme** and create the layout like

**app\design\frontend\sample\sample-theme\magento_theme\page_layout\custom_home.xml**

> `<?xml version="1.0"?>
>   <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
>           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
>       <update handle="empty"/>
>       <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
>           <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
>           <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
>           <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
>       </referenceContainer>
>   </layout>`

**app\design\frontend\accu\accu-theme\magento_theme\layouts.xml**

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>   <page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"              xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
>       <layout id="custom_home">
>           <label translate="true">Custom Home</label>
>       </layout>
>   </page_layouts>`

this is my code. In my admin panel **Content->Pages** in Home-Page not showing the custom-home page. Any one help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move 
`app\design\frontend\sample\sample-theme\magento_theme\page_layout\custom_home.xml`

to

`app\design\frontend\accu\accu-theme\Magento_Theme\page_layout\custom_home.xml`

in below, rename `magento_theme` to `Magento_Theme`

`app\design\frontend\accu\accu-theme\magento_theme\layouts.xml`

to

`app\design\frontend\accu\accu-theme\Magento_Theme\layouts.xml`

Else everything looks perfect.

Feel free for any query

======EDIT ============

update `app\design\frontend\accu\accu-theme\Magento_Theme\page_layout\custom_home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
      <update handle="empty"/>
      <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
          <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
          <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>

          <referenceContainer name="content"> <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" output="toHtml" template="homepage.phtml"/> </referenceContainer>

          <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
      </referenceContainer>
  </layout>
```

Comment: its it working fine

Comment: now i need to add my homepage.phtml file into the home page custom design

Comment: may I know for what purpose you want to add homepage.phtml

Comment: i need create the custom page design

Comment: i am new to magento i need to create e-commerce web site using magent,i dont know how to work in magento

Comment: @RaviKumar,  you can not add homepage.phtml for whole page but you can refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106535/magento-2-creating-a-custom-layout

Comment: update content area using `<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="homepage.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>`

Comment: i don't understand where i need to place this code

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: thanks.next i need to add menus in my header,now the default theme menu is showing,how to add my new menus

Comment: which folder i need to place the homepage.phtml file

Comment: app\design\frontend\accu\accu-theme\Magento_Theme\templates\

Comment: i have place correct folder but i did not get the correct result

Answer (score 0):

Pleaser refer to this link: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-add-a-new-cms-page-magento-2.html

You can create a custom homepage using cms page. In that link has the same idea on how to set it as your default homepage.

I hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: its working. But i need to create the custom template like above

Answer (score 0):

For that you should create page layout folder in the directory of your Magento theme where you copy a file with custom template. In that file you assign the appearance of the page. As a base file you can use any of predefined (for example app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/page_layout/1column.xml).The next step is going to be layouts.xml file creation in Magento Theme directory of your theme. Id attribute of layout tag should correspond to name of the page template file you previously created, and the content of label tag defines the template name in admin panel of the website. It’s better to create a new CMS page for the custom homepage. In order to do that just navigate to Content> Elements> Pages and click Add New Page button. Further it’s necessary to assign previously created template to this page. Just navigate to Design tab and choose the template in the Layout drop-down. So after you created a new CMS page and assigned the required template to it, you should assign this page as a Homepage for a certain store. Just navigate to Stores> Settings> Configuration, then in the left sidebar choose General Web and open the Default Pages tab. And the next step you should do is to select the webstore where you want the homepage to be changed. Next in the CMS Home Page drop-down list select the page you want to make Home Page for the certain store. Don’t forget to save all changes and flush the website cache.

here you can find the description of this process: https://belvg.com/blog/creating-a-custom-homepage-template-in-magento-2-1-5.html