# Set Custom CMS page as a home page programatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, home-page

How to set a custom CMS page as my Magento home page programmatically.

Comment: why you need to add it pragmatically as there is an options in admin available to set CMS page as a home page.

Comment: please review this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169372/creating-a-custom-homepage-template-in-magento2-1-5

Comment: @ShorabhKumarGupta,please  check the question before commenting any reference url

Comment: @AasimGoriya I am working on custom module, where i need to upgrade my default page to my custom page. I know i can set it from admin. But i want to do it by programmatically in my custom module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set default value with following code.

```
 public function __construct(\Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $_resourceConfig)
    {
        $this->_resourceConfig = $_resourceConfig;
    }

        $this->_resourceConfig->saveConfig('web/default/cms_home_page', 'youridentifier', 'default', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using  `Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface` , you can set a store config value

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

    /**
     *  @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface
     */
    protected $configWriter;

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter
     */
    public function __construct(
        ....
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter
        .....
    )
    {
        $this->configWriter = $configWriter;
    }

    $this->configWriter->save('web/default/cms_home_page',  $CMSPAGEIdentifier, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);
```